# Packer "azure-arm" fails when running in parallel

Tags: azure, packer

I want to execute several builds of Packer "azure-arm" in parallel as jobs in Azure DevOps
I can't use multiple `builders` in the same template because they have to have different `provisioners`
If I run multiple jobs in parallel (on different agents) I'm getting the following errors (randomly): 
[image]

[image]

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: this doesnt look like it would work if there would be only a single instance, tbh

Comment: @4c74356b41sorry, I didn't get your point

Comment: the point is- this is an auth issue, doesnt matter if its a single instance or multiple ones